# How to get 32 by using +1 , +1 , ×3 , ×3 , ÷2 , ÷2, ^2, ^2?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, knowledge, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

How to get 32 by using +1,+1,×3,×3,÷2,÷2,^2,^2?
(The last two operators are 'squaring'.)

Comment: would you please clarify what number to start from? I assume it is zero, as do the responders (so far), but the question as it stands does not contain that restriction - it doesn't even mention use of a calculator device, which commonly start from implicit zero

Comment: Why not just +1+1... = 32?

Comment: @S.S.Anne I think we're supposed to use exactly two of each, otherwise the repetition in the listing would be rather redundant.

Comment: I hope people make more of these puzzles so I can make more diagrams (wink wink).

Comment: Since your solution has an implicit 0 and implicit parens, would `(+ 1 * 3) ** (2 ** (2 * (3 + 1))) / 2 / 2` be allowed? The expressions has the desired 8 numbers and 8 operations. I realize it isn't equal to 32, it's just an example.

Comment: @EricDuminil well, another thing dictated by the calculator setup - which the question apparently is meant to imply - are strictly left-associative parentheses, not arbitrary ones.

Comment: @LeifWillerts that's a good point. It should be explicit, then.

Answer (score 40):

I like Glorfindel's answer as it takes you **through** an example solution, and I recommend his answer. Just to show some underlying beauty and complexity of this puzzle, I created a diagram (directed multigraph) that shows all possible results (that yield integers) of permuting these operations. You'll have to open the image in another tab and magnify to follow it in detail. I hope you enjoy.

Note that the green nodes are those where at least one sequence of the operations terminates there.

## Starting at zero:

> [image]

## Starting at one:

Since there might be some interest in this case, here's a similar map.

> It is not actually possible to get from 1 to 32 using exactly these 8 operations.
>  [image]

## Bonus Information

> I checked every graph that starts at 0 up through 32, and confirmed that none of the other graphs terminate at 32. What's more, the answer given by Glorfindel is the *only* solution. This puzzle makes me happy.

Comment: Nice! If I'm reading the graph correctly, it looks like the solution is unique.

Comment: @Glorfindel That's my understanding as well, assuming we use each of the eight given operations exactly once.

Comment: It is not actually possible to get from 1 to 32 using exactly these 8 operations.

Comment: one suggestion for improvement: in some way dinstinguish the possible terminal nodes from the always transitory ones. @Galen could you provide us with your code?

Comment: @LeifWillerts Interesting idea. I just tried colouring the terminal nodes in the starting at zero graph, but the only node that is always transitory is the starting node, zero.

Comment: what happened to that poor 12 x3 arrow?

Comment: @Exal Which graph?

Comment: @Exal Oh, I see it kinked. That is a consequence of the drawing algorithm.

Comment: @Galen makes sense, i just felt bad for it :D

Comment: @LeifWillerts I've added colour to the terminal nodes of the 'starts at 1 graph` for you since there's more of a mix on where the solutions terminate.

Comment: @Exal Me too. :P

Comment: @LeifWillerts And I have included the terminal node colouring for the 'start at zero' graph as well.

Comment: I hope people make more of these puzzles so I can make more diagrams (wink wink).

Comment: @Galen excellent solution. +1. Would you mind sharing tool/algorithm you did apply via here or an a link?

Comment: @snr The algorithm is just brute force, generated with Python. Graphviz compiles the PDF. GIMP exports from PDF to PNG.

Comment: @Galen Sharing code?

Comment: @Galen: Nice diagrams. Graphviz can export to PNG directly, BTW.

Comment: @EricDuminil Thanks! Using GIMP was the just the first thing that came to mind at the time, but I'll check the docs for graphviz.

Comment: @Galen I don't think you are correct on the 0-starting graph. As an easy and obvious example, there is no way to reach 2304 as a terminal

Comment: @LeifWillerts Does ('/2', '/2', '+1', '*3', '+1', '^2', '*3', '^2') -> 2304?

Comment: I think you just gotta burn a couple '/2' at the beginning.

Comment: 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 16 -> 48 -> 2304

Comment: @Galen WOW this answer is an A+. I noted from the comment you used brute-force in Python (with Graphiz) mind to share more about your code and strategy to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: @adhg Thanks! Probably the most important time-saver is to know to use ```permutations``` from the ```itertools``` library. The strategy is to loop over all permutations of operations, as well as each application of the operation, collecting the graph relations as you go along.

Comment: @Galen got it! Much appreciated.

Comment: @Galen can you please put 0 on top and not in the middle of a bunch of the other numbers? I was confused before I zoomed in and found it.

Comment: @Boris Thanks for the constructive feedback; I totally get it. Offhand I know there are different layout algorithms I could try. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Galen Graphs like these tend to make me drool uncontrollably, they are so ... soothing. I love these and tend to analyze them and follow the paths for no good reason whatsoever. Tremendous work! For some reason they reminded me of graphs representing the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) which I also liked. One thing that bothered me however is that the second graph (exported in JPG format) has visible artifacts, I wish it was a PNG image like the first one.

Comment: @Tomalla Me too! Thanks! I thought I had uploaded with PNG, but I see it is JPG. I tried to reupload with a PNG but it is auto-converted to JPG. I'm guessing when the image is sufficiently large that SE converts it to JPG :(

Comment: @Galen I still find it exceedingly hard to believe that, starting from 0, all numbers reachable with a subset of the operations are also reachable using exactly all.

Comment: @LeifWillerts That is actually really easy to explain. The first node ("0") can "swallop up" almost every operator. That's why if you choose (almost) any subset of operations and wind up with a result, you can easily discard the rest by applying them first to "0". Note however that the only operator which cannot be discarded that way is the operator "+1". That's why "+1" must be included in every subset and the node "0" is the only one which is not obtainable (i.e. is not green).

Comment: Yeah, I should have thought of the idempotence on 0 (and I think that, as it happens, part of me not realizing it just by looking at the graph and mostly ignoring the node contents was that 0 was not on top as mentioned by @Boris hehe). But how is there not a single number reachable only by sequences containing exactly one +1 (so that the entire set of operations does not work)?

Comment: @LeifWillerts It does a feel  little uncanny that turns out that way as this is not alway true. My suspicion is that the self-loops [f(a) == a] and antiparallel edges [f(a)==b, f(b)==a] produce some counterintuitive results. There's also a selection bias in the diagram as I have not included any of the non-integer results, which are potentially numerous.

Comment: @Galen why didn't you include fractions? +1 +1 /2 /2

Comment: @Boris I don't exactly recall. :o I guess the integers were what I was curious about at the time.

Comment: I really appreciate all the constructive feedback and critical thinking in the comments of this answer. It is really cool to see that I made something that gets people thinking, which is what puzzles are about after all :)

Comment: Galen in fact just that selection is an important part of it: /2 doesn't produce integers if the second +1 hasn't been used yet (as you can only have 0 or 3^n then, or of course you already left the integers by halving before), so passing only through the integers implies either already having used the second +1 (which means that all remaining operations can be prepended without change as @Tomalla said), being still on 0 (which indeed can not be a terminal state), or currently holding a power of 3 (up to ^8).

Comment: But now still I struggle to figure out how the path to 3^8=6561, which is 0 [any number of /2s] +1 *3 *3 ^2 ^2, can incorporate another +1 because most operations are taken up in a way that is hard to replace on a steep path up the 3^ns.

Comment: @LeifWillerts I see what you mean. I think there are 4 ways to get 6561. One of them is the sequence `['+1', '+1', '*3', '*3', '^2', '/2', '/2', '^2']`.

Comment: ah, so since all 3^n that are reachable at all are so without /2 and the second +1, this "starting at 2 instead of 1" trick can always yield them with all operations included. Okay, that covers the last remaining case, thank you so much!

Comment: @Boris I've quickly whipped up graphs including the fractions. They're *a lot* bigger, I've hosted them on EasyZoom to make them easy to view [here](https://www.easyzoom.com/imageaccess/fe3adab0cdc04b1cae9f02c9cc9537a7) (floating point precision) and [here](https://www.easyzoom.com/imageaccess/15d3052aef39491ea79a8e83a89f6e93) (with fractions). What's interesting is that there are numbers which are unobtainable, like: 1/8, 3/8, 1/32 etc. Normally skipping fractional numbers is justified, because once you get one you won't be able to get an integer out of it anyways. I just couldn't resist.

Comment: @Tomalla Nice work! I see easy zoom allows you store up to 2 GB for free. Are you happy with their service?

Comment: @Galen Hard for me to tell since the first time I got acquainted with their services was less than 30 minutes ago ;)

Comment: Good answer. But I feel that it is better to have a top down approach. To understand what I am saying, please see the answer that I have added a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 35):

Assuming you start with 0 (like on a calculator), this should work:

> $$0 \times 3 = 0$$
>  $$0 + 1 = 1$$
>  $$1 \times 3 = 3$$
>  $$3 + 1 = 4$$
>  $$4^2 = 16$$
>  $$16 \div 2 = 8$$
>  $$8^2 = 64$$
>  $$64 \div 2 = 32$$

Comment: Nice answer---I seem to have lost my ability to solve these things as I get older.....I get lost in the endlessly bifurcating trees.  But what bothers me about some of these puzzles is that the zero (no matter how you arrive to it) can act as a way to "throw away" subsequent operations, no?  For instance, you hucked out the x3 here.  You could just as easily have thrown out any of the multiplications, divisions, and exponents.  *Nothing wrong with that at all*, it's all part of the rules.  But it seems less ....... interesting to me to allow it somehow.  I wonder how a rule might limit that?

Comment: A possible rule would be to start with $x$ and forbid 0 as an intermediate result?

Comment: @Glorfindel Good one. Perhaps another could be that no two adjacent numbers in the calculation sequence can be equal, thus operations must always change the number. In some ways that is limiting, but it could apply to any collection of operations.

Comment: another (more restrictive)  rule would be to require each intermediate result to be distinct.

Answer (score 15):

I don't know how I got to this question from Stack Overflow... But here is the solution and the Python code for checking every combination:

> ((((((((0*3)+1)*3)+1)**2)/2.0)**2)/2.0)

````
lis = ['+1', '+1', '*3', '*3', '/2.0', '/2.0', '**2', '**2']
result = set()
def sol(lis, current, res, result):

    if not lis and res == 32:
        result.add(current)
        return

    for i in range(len(lis)):
        c = f"({current}{lis[i]})"
        sol(lis[:i] + lis[i+1:], c, eval("res"+lis[i]), result)
sol(lis, 0, 0, result)
print(result)
```
````

Comment: Check out my answer to this question! You can **see** all the combinations that produce integers.

Comment: You got here via the Hot Network Questions list, like many. Welcome!

Comment: @Galen the code style I mention ??

Comment: @Frank Nice recursive definition! I'm a fan of recursion.

Answer (score 12):

I noticed that there was a lot of emphasis around powers of 2, and that gave me an idea:

> I started from the solution and brute-forced my way backwards. 
>  This puzzle can be rephrased as something like: Starting at 32, use these operators sequentially to get to 0: 
>  $$-1, -1, \div 3, \div 3, \times 2, \times 2, \sqrt(n), \sqrt(n)$$

Notably:

> This set of inverse operations has a smaller search space because dividing by 3 and taking the square root are much more restrictive in their use.

My work:

> $$32 \times 2 = 64$$
>  $$\sqrt(64) = 8$$
>  $$8 \times 2 = 16$$
>  $$\sqrt(16)= 4$$
>  $$4-1 = 3$$
>  $$3 \div 3 = 1$$
>  $$1-1 = 0$$
>  $$0 \div 3 = 0$$
>  Then all you have to do is re-invert the operations (and reverse their order) to get the answer of
>  $$\times 3, +1, \times 3, +1, (n)^2, \div 2, (n)^2, \div 2$$

Comment: Welcome to [Puzzling.SE]! This is actually the method I used (at least to get to 4).

Answer (score 5):

This solution reduces the problem to a simpler one using each operation's effect on prime factorization.

> We begin with $0+1=1=2^03^0$.
>  
>  Each step is represented by the form: $2^n3^m$.
>  We have the following operations:
>
>  $(*3)$ yields $2^n3^{m+1}$
>
>  $(/2)$ yields $2^{n-1}3^m$
>
>  $(\hat{}2)$ yields $2^{2n}3^{2m}$
>
>  and $(+1)$ "randomly" shuffles/introduces new exponents. Our desired number is $2^5=32$.
>  The only reasonable first step is to increase the exponents from zero, so we can apply:
>  $$2^03^0*3=2^03^1$$
>  We then use our only chance to get rid of the $3$ factor entirely:
>  
>  $$2^03^1+1=2^23^0$$ 
>
>  We must get from $2^2\rightarrow2^5$, so let's reduce the problem to solving $2\rightarrow5$ using the remaining four operations (on the exponent): $(-1), (-1), (*2), (*2)$. Let's start backwards from $5$:
>
>  The last operation must have been $6-1=5$ (because $2.5*2$ is unreachable),
>
>  Next must have been $3*2=6$, (cannot be $7-1=6$, because $2*2*2\neq7$),
>
>  $3$ is odd, so we came from $4-1=3$, and finally $2*2=4$.
>
>  Converting everything back, we have performed the following:
>  $$(((0+1)*3+1)^2/2)^2/2=32$$

Pretty contrived but it kind of forces the solution without exhausting all the possibilities!

Comment: There are two copies of x3. You have only used one.

Comment: A mathematical explanation with useful, formal hints how this kind of problem can be approached. The other x3 is easy to include.

Answer (score 4):

I had a lot of fun with this one! First, as others did, I worked out it could "only" be done starting from one particular number, then saw Glorfindel's answer and realised that if

> 4 is a waypoint, then so is -4, because -4^2 is also 16.

So I worked backwards from that and found

> a new starting point of -8/9.

Then it occurred to me that

> all the operations are reversible on the complex plane

so I modified the operations accordingly and wrote a solver, also as an exercise in the C++ STL, tuples, lambdas and all that fancy stuff, wrote the output to a file and fed it into gnuplot.

This is the resulting plot, showing

> all 161,280 possible starting points
>  NB: there are duplicates I haven't removed;
>  there are more results than 8! (40,320) because a complex number has two square roots
>  [image: gnuplot of the results]

Edit: After posting I found a way to remove duplicates, which if I got the logic right means there are

> 4950 unique answers, using a difference of 0.0001 in both parts.

Edit: Can I post an example?

> 32 -1 /3 -sqrt -sqrt -1 *2 *2 /3 = -1.3333 - i2.3906

Comment: What a cool generalization! I *love* it!

Comment: could you post an example? :)

Answer (score 1):

In response to the assertion that it cannot be done starting with 1, here is a method that may work, depending on exactly how the rules are applied.

> $$(1) \times 3 = 3$$
>  $$3 + 1 = 4$$
>  $${4 \div 2} = 2$$
>  $$2^2 = 4$$
>  $${4 \div 2} = 2$$
>  $$2^{2+1 \times 3} = 2^5$$
>  $$2^5 = 32$$

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that we are looking for an integer solution. With this assumption, here is a top down  approach that nobody else has used. The first question that needs to be asked is is that If a solution exists then what will be the last operator that would be used .

The last operator cannot be ×3 or ^2 as no integer × 3 = 32 nor (any integer)^2 = 32 . Therefore, the last operator to be used has to be either +1 or ÷2 . Therefore the numbers that are possible right before the last operator was used was either 31 (since 31+1= 32) or  64 ( since 64/2= 32).  The following picture shows that there are only 5 ways to get to 32 using a total of 2 operations. [image]

The image below shows a complete expansion of one of the 5 paths shown above. As has been mentioned in the previous answers, we can see in the image below that there is indeed a path starting from 0 such that using all the 8 operators exactly once, we can get to 32.

[image]