# What's the graph relation? #4

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, graph-theory, chemistry

What's the relation that joins the nodes?

[image]

Previous

- [What's the graph relation? #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97643/whats-the-graph-relation-1)
- [What's the graph relation? #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97644/whats-the-graph-relation-2)
- [What's the graph relation? #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98254/whats-the-graph-relation-3)

Comment: Does colour matters?

Comment: @CulverKwan The colours are useful information, but you might not 'need' them to figure out the puzzle.

Comment: If you like big graphs, also check out https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97439/how-to-get-32-by-using-1-1-%c3%973-%c3%973-%c3%b72-%c3%b72-2-2/97458#97458

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the relationship is:

> Two numbers are adjacent if the elements with the corresponding atomic numbers are in adjacent boxes on the extended periodic table of elements (where the lanthanides and actinides are inserted into the table, and not excerpted to the bottom).